# how can i compare data in 2 files to identify common and unique data?

Tags: command-line, files, text

How can I compare data in 2 files to identify common and unique data ? I can't do it line by line because I have file 1 which contains say 100 id/codes/number-set and I want to compare a file 2 to file 1.

The thing is that file 2 contains a subset of data in file 1 and also data unique to file 2, for example:

```
file 1      file 2
1            1
2            a
3            2
4            b
5            3 
6            c
```

How can I compare both files to identify data that is common and unique to each files? `diff` can't seem to do the job.

Comment: @CarlH good grief! This is perfectly on topic here. There are tools like `diff` and `comm` among others that can do it natively and are part of the basic UNIX tool set. What's more, this question would not be well received on SO at all, it has no code and would expect others to just write the entire program for the OP. Please be careful when suggesting users post elsewhere. Be sure you understand the scope of both sites before making such suggestions in the future.

Answer (score 7):

No matter if your file1 and file2 are sorted or not, use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command as follows:

#### unique data in file1:

```bsh
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
4
5
6
```

#### unique data in file2:

```bsh
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2
a
b
c
```

#### common data:

```bsh
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} ($0 in a)' file1 file2
1
2
3
```

---

#### Explanation:

```bsh
NR==FNR    - Execute next block for 1st file only
a[$0]      - Create an associative array with key as '$0' (whole line) and copy that into it as its content.
next       - move to next row
($0 in a)  - For each line saved in `a` array:
             print the common lines from 1st and 2nd file "($0 in a)' file1 file2"
             or unique lines in 1st file only "!($0 in a)' file2 file1"
             or unique lines in 2nd file only "!($0 in a)' file1 file2"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what [`comm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/comm.1.html) is for:

```
$ comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
        1
        2
        3
4
5
6
    a
    b
    c
```

The first column is lines only appearing in file 1
The second column is lines only appearing in file 2
The third column is lines common to both files

`comm` requires the input files to be sorted

To *exclude* any column from appearing, add an option with that column number. For example, to see only the lines in common, use `comm -12 ...` or the lines that are only in file2, `comm -13 ...`

Answer (score 0):

`xxdiff` is unmatched if you just need to graphically see the changes between two files (or directories!):

[image]

Like regular `diff` and `comm`, your input files should be sorted first.

```
sort file1.txt > file1.txt.sorted
sort file2.txt > file2.txt.sorted
xxdiff file1.txt.sorted file2.txt.sorted
```